# Issue in sound cloud widget API

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I am using sound cloud pro account for our site in that I am uploading sound into sound cloud server using below code

```
var upload = SC.upload({
    file: file,
    title: 'asdwer523645erwef',
    genre: 'Learning'
});
```

On upload complete i am getting uploaded track details in below code

```
upload.then(function (track) {
    alert('Upload is done! Check your sound at ' + track.id);
});
```

Now i am bind that track using below code

```
SC.Widget(document.getElementById('soundcloud_widget'));
```

but getting error "We're still processing this track or playlist." like below image.

[image]

Can anyone solve this error? your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: sounds like it will come back in a few minutes

Comment: I have updated tags now it will not come back.